# Is there a quick way to delete all shortcuts in Visual Studio 10?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2010

VS10 is chock-full of shortcuts, most of which I find useless and sometimes even annoying. I would like to clear all of them, and then just set up the handful of shortcuts I actually want / use. Trawling through the list and deleting each manually is pretty tedious.

Is there a quick way of nuking all the shortcuts at once?

Maybe some cheap scripting? It doesn't have to be elegant.

( I realize I may lose things like "arrow-left in editor", but I can easily fix these few things ).

Comment: Okay, clearly the implementers of the keyboard management were not thinking people would actually use these features. The UI is disgusting and broken.

Can keyboard bindings be edited manually in a config file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a Macro (or a PowerShell script in 2012+) that makes the changes you want.  I don't have a working version of VS 2010 right now to test with, but something like this should work:

```
Sub ClearBindings()
    Dim cmd As Command
    Dim props As EnvDTE.Properties = DTE.Properties("Environment", "Keyboard")
    Dim prop As EnvDTE.Property

    ' Because you cannot programmatically change the default keyboard 
    ' mapping scheme settings, you must first make a copy of the 
    ' Default Settings for the Keyboard Mapping Scheme.
    prop = props.Item("SchemeName")
    ' Sets the Scheme property value to a new keyboard scheme.
    ' This saves the old keyboard mapping scheme and allows you 
    ' to add new key mappings.
    prop.Value = "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NoKeyBindings.vsk"

    For Each cmd In DTE.Commands
        cmd.Bindings = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in VS10 Pro ( "parameter is incorrect" argument exception on the attempt to get the 'Scheme' property ), but voted up because it's a good starting point.

Comment: @bernz, sorry, I think the correct name is "SchemeName", I've updated

Comment: For reference see:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228778.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and corrections. ( I realize this response is extremely latent, but the SE network's credential system is so annoyingly obtuse, I rarely log in ).